# Webpack & HtmlWebpackPlugin: Injection of chunks into custom template doesn't work

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I'm using Webpack/HtmlWebpackPlugin with multiple entry points & chunks to compile an AngularJS application. I'll need the JS injected somewhere in the middle of the HTML template, so I use

```
<% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
<script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %>"></script>
<% } %>
```

as described here: https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template/blob/master/index.ejs. The template get's compiled, but no script-tags are inserted for my chunks. What's wrong?

**My relevant Webpack configuration [webpack.prod.config.js]:**

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const common = require('./webpack.base.config.js');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.min.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist.prod')
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src-ts-store/landingpage_store.liquid.ejs',
        filename: 'landingpage_store.liquid',
        base: {href: '/apps/sgp'},
        inject: false,/* instead using this:  https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/386 , https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template */
        chunks: ['app-store','defaultVendors','dptCommon']
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src-ts-admin/landingpage_admin.html.ejs',
        filename: 'landingpage_admin.html',
        base: {href: '/frontend-admin/'},
        inject: false,/* instead using this:  https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/386 , https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template */
        chunks: ['app-admin','defaultVendors','dptCommon']
      })
    ]
});
```

**The relevant part of the template [landingpage_admin.html.ejs]**

```
<html ng-app="DPT" ng-controller="appController">
 <script src="app.environment.var.js"></script>
 <link href="plugins/bootstrap-dropdown-removed-typography.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


 <% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
 <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %>"></script>
 <% } %>


 <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b6b551a0d0.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 [...]
```

**The relevant console output**

```
Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
     2 assets
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_1 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_1
    [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src-ts-store/landingpage_store.liquid.ejs 2.26 KiB {0} [built]
    [1] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src-ts-admin/landingpage_admin.html.ejs 12 KiB {1} [built]
```

Answer (score 7):

I have found https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template/issues/69#issuecomment-376872044 and without truly understanding what is actually going wrong I have changed

```
<% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %>
    <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %>"></script>
<% } %>
```

to the following and it fixed the issue for me:

```
<% for (var chunk in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js) { %>
    <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js[chunk]%>"></script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: my hero! Why in the world will `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.headTags %>` not work

Comment: Very helpful! For reference, in version 4.0.0 of html-webpack-plugin, the "chunks" property was removed, which is why chunks are now referenced as the [chunk] property of files.js instead.